# Write formula to excel cell using VB.NET (What is wrong with this code?)

Tags: vb.net, excel, formula

I want to sum a range from a sheet from one excel workbook and write it to another workbook. I came up with a following code but it is not working.

1) it opens a file open windows which asks me to select workbook to update

2) after selecting a workbook it writes "0" as a value.

Code:

```
Dim xl1 As New Excel.Application
Dim xl2 As New Excel.Application

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook

Dim st1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim st2 As Excel.Worksheet

wb1 = xl1.Workbooks.Open("F:\excelsumtest\file1.xlsx")
wb2 = xl2.Workbooks.Open("F:\excelsumtest\file2.xlsx")

st1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)
st2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)

st2.Cells(1, 1).formula = "=Sum(st1!A1:S1)"
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
wb2 = xl2.Workbooks.Open("F:\excelsumtest\file2.xlsx")
'to this:
wb2 = xl1.Workbooks.Open("F:\excelsumtest\file2.xlsx")
```

I'm tying both workbooks to 1 instance of an Excel application.  This isn't tested, but I think that this way, Excel will understand that it's the worksheet from the xl1 workbook that you're trying to insert.

If not, you might have to fully define the workbook you're referencing in your formula.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1.  Can't see any good reason for two instances of Excel, and the formula definitely won't recognize st1 across instances.

Comment: @Doug, I agree. I haven't ever had to use 2 separate Excel instances for whatever I needed to accomplish. Plus, I feel that it's more limited, for example, using the Office clipboard across instances (I've had weird issues with that when 2 instances were used).

Comment: @joseph4tw: This time again it asked me to select a file but it wrote the formula. Now it shows REF. is there any way to smoothly write formula without opening this file open dialog?

Comment: it is solved. I wrote the formula in excel first and then copied it in VB.NET code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Dim xlsApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application 
xlsApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```